# How to trigger youtube infinite scroll in bash

Tags: html, bash, shell, youtube, wget

I'm trying to download youtube page after some search using wget in bash. The problem is that wget only downloads an html of the first page without any scrolling down. I need to trigger youtube's infinite scroll atleast to some point to display more results.

I'm working on youtube-tool in bash and now i'm stucked at this point. I would like to list further in the results.

Comment: This isn't going to be a wget request, it will be a curl one.  Open up the debugger and watch the AJAX calls.  You can right click inside of the debugger and usually get the curl request used.

Comment: @jasonmclose how can i create curl request to scroll the page?

Comment: What happens on infinite scroll is when you scroll to/near the bottom, some javascript runs and fetches more content, then adds it to the page dynamically. You'd have to parse and run the javascript, send it the right events, and handle the changes it makes.

Comment: so it is not possible to do it inside bash or just with bash commands? (without JS, PHP, ..)

Comment: I'm not going to say it's not possible, but it's certainly a hefty project.  I would look at some Python libraries that are specifically built for making calls like this.